# JSON Parsing through all elements in Java using the org.json library?

Tags: java, json, org.json

I'm trying to parse through all records from the json file. I currently have 3 records with 20 different objects inside each record. When I perform the following functions it only grabs the first element and the objects inside it, how do I continue to grab the other elements from the json file. Here is what I'm using.

```
// Read from JSON file using the readallBytes method and put it in the contents variable
String contents = new String((Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(first))));

// Create JSON object to put the contents into it to look up keys for easy data extraction
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(contents);
```

I have noticed that contents variable does show all 3 elements but once it's put inside a JSONObject it only takes the first element. Need to find out how to iterate through the rest of the 3 elements. The json file has he format below:

any help is fully appreciated it.

```
{
  "id": 117,
  "name": "Table Rock Sheet",
  "type": "physical",
  "sku": "JDE1353",
  "description": "<p><\/p>",
  "weight": 0.3,
  "width": 3,
  "depth": 3,
  "height": 1,
  "price": 8.6,
  "cost_price": 0,
  "retail_price": 5.99,
  "sale_price": 8.69,
  "map_price": 0,
  "tax_class_id": 0,
  "product_tax_code": "",
  "calculated_price": 8.69,
  "categories": [
    33
  ]
},
{
  "id": 118,
  "name": "Car Jack Stand",
  "type": "physical",
  "sku": "35353",
  "description": "<p><\/p>",
  "weight": 0.3,
  "width": 3.25,
  "depth": 3.75,
  "height": 0.25,
  "price": 8.6,
  "cost_price": 0,
  "retail_price": 5.99,
  "sale_price": 8.69,
  "map_price": 0,
  "tax_class_id": 0,
  "product_tax_code": "",
  "calculated_price": 8.69,
  "categories": [
    35,
    39,
    42
  ]
},
{
  "id": 119,
  "name": "Wildlife Painting Portrate",
  "type": "physical",
  "sku": "TER35333",
  "description": "<p><\/p>",
  "weight": 0.3,
  "width": 0.25,
  "depth": 3.25,
  "height": 3.75,
  "price": 7.92,
  "cost_price": 0,
  "retail_price": 4.99,
  "sale_price": 8,
  "map_price": 0,
  "tax_class_id": 0,
  "product_tax_code": "",
  "calculated_price": 8,
  "categories": [
    35,
    39,
    42
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your content is not a valid JSON. It is a sequence of 3 JSON Objects, and they are not arranged in JSON array. So, what happens you read your content and parse an Object. It finishes to read a complete JSON Object and stops. If you want to change your file to valid JSON you need to enclose it into square brackets.[...]. The read it as JSONArray. it will read it as a JSONArray that includes 3 JSONObjects.
Also I would suggest to switch from org.json library to Jackson-JSON also known as Faster-XML. The defacto standard JSON library. (Or Google's Gson based on Jackson-JSON). See  Jackson home [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) tutorial - [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson), Maven artifacts - [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-json-org) and javadoc for ObjectMapper class - [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html). In that class see methods `readValue(...)` and `writeValueAsString(...)`